# Как расположить текст вокруг изображения в JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, scene-builder

Пишу десктоп приложение на JavaFX и Scene Builder.

Есть AnchorPane, к котором расположен лейбл, в этом лейбле есть текст и изображение.

Текст расположен после изображения, но когда его становится больше, он не уходит под картинку, картинка сдвигается вместе с ним.

Вот,что у меня есть :

```
@FXML  private AnchorPane previewCard;
@FXML  private Label lb_randomCard;
@FXML  private ImageView previewImage;

@FXML
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

lb_previewCard.wrapTextProperty().bind(previewCard.prefWidthProperty());

}
```

[image: screen 1]

[image: screen 2]

[image: screen 3]

**Как добиться вот такого расположения текста?**

[image: screen 4]

Comment: Вы можете использовать WebView, в который подгрузите свёрстанную страницу с изображением и текстом, и с заданным форматированием.

Comment: такой вариант не подойдет, это карточка, она рандомно появляется на поле, и там постоянно меняется текст и изображения. Текст берется из базы дванных SQLite, а изображения из папки программы. Этих карточек овер дофига)

Comment: @Range а возможно ли в Моем Anchor Pane разместить WebView шаблон? то есть в этом WebView сделать только ImageView и поле для текст, как этот текст будет располагаться, а уже приходящие данные просто будут подстраиваться под этот шаблон?

Comment: Из вариантов - формировать html - код на лету, добавляя в него ссылки на картинки и сам текст. И уже код отправлять в WebView. По производительности не знаю, не стояло такой задачи.

Comment: @Range страница html может располагаться в папке программы? моя программа должна работать без интернета в оффлайн режиме

Comment: Вы можете сформировать страницу в коде, текстово. Сложить нужные элементы в String и отправить переменную в WebView. Пример:

String html = "<html><h1>Hello</h1><h2>Hello</h2></html>";
webEngine.loadContent(html);